# How to generating table that will have 3 columns per row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I use Vue 2.

I generate table from the collection:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(type, typeIndex) in getAllUpgradeTypes" :key="typeIndex">
          <td>
            <imageDesc
              style="margin-left: 10px"
              :title="type"
              :text="'Select an Option'"
              :zoneId="selectedZone.id"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Currently, the table created with multiple rows, each row has only one column and shows one item inside the column.

My question how can I generate a table which will contain 3 columns per row?

Comment: Would you just put 3 <td> elements 'under' the <tr>?

Answer (score 3):

There at least a couple of different patterns you could use for this.  One involves rearranging your data before iterating it in the template, another doesn't.  I'll show you both.

In both cases, use a data property to hold the number of columns:

```js
data: () => ({
  numCols: 3
})
```

### Reorganize the data into a 2D array

Instead of one array with all your items, use a computed to reorganize the data into a multi-dimensional array of rows and columns:

```
computed: {
  arrangedData() {
    const arrangedData = [];
    this.getAllUpgradeTypes.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (index % this.numCols === 0) {
        arrangedData.push([])
      }
      arrangedData[arrangedData.length - 1].push(item);
    });
    return arrangedData;
  }
}
```

Iterate the data like this:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in arrangedData" :key="rowIndex">
    <td v-for="(type, typeIndex) in row" :key="`${rowIndex}:${typeIndex}`">
      {{ type }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    getAllUpgradeTypes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'],
    numCols: 3
  }),
  computed: {
    arrangedData() {
      const arrangedData = [];
      this.getAllUpgradeTypes.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (index % this.numCols === 0) {
          arrangedData.push([])
        }
        arrangedData[arrangedData.length - 1].push(item);
      });
      return arrangedData;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td { width: 40px }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in arrangedData" :key="rowIndex">
      <td v-for="(type, typeIndex) in row" :key="`${rowIndex}:${typeIndex}`">
        {{ type }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

### -or-

### Calculate the number of rows

The other way involves using a computed to calculate the number of rows.  It's less code, but then `type` gets an ugly syntax in the template:

```js
computed: {
  numRows() {
    return Math.ceil(this.getAllUpgradeTypes.length / this.numCols);
  }
}
```

Iterate the data like this:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr v-for="(row, indexRow) in numRows">
    <td v-for="(col, indexCol) in numCols">
      {{ getAllUpgradeTypes[(indexRow * numCols) + indexCol] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    getAllUpgradeTypes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'],
    numCols: 3
  }),
  computed: {
    numRows() {
      return Math.ceil(this.getAllUpgradeTypes.length / this.numCols);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td { width: 40px; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(row, indexRow) in numRows" :key="indexRow">
      <td v-for="(type, indexCol) in numCols" :key="`${rowIndex}:${typeIndex}`">
        {{ getAllUpgradeTypes[(indexRow * numCols) + indexCol] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

There are probably some variations on these options but I think the first is probably the best for the template clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to a similar issue.  I needed to generate a printable page and display information from a table in our database.  The appearance of the page required me to have 3 fixed-size rows and 3 fixed-size columns per row.

I added styling to give it a grid-like appearance, but here is how I generated the table with page breaks after 3 rows:

This is where I have the table setup in the HTML (cshtml) file:

```
<table id="employee-table" class="m-auto">

</table>
```

Here is my JavaScript function which is located in an external JS file (don't forget to reference the file in your HTML if that's how you're setting it up)

```
function GeneratePrintablePDF(employeeData) {
    document.getElementById('loader').classList.add('hidden'); //this is just the "loading" spinner for when the page is loading
    dataContainer = document.getElementById('employee-table');

    numberOfRows = employeeData.length / 3;

    if (employeeData % 3 != 0) {
        numberOfRows = Math.trunc(numberOfRows);
        numberOfRows += 1;
    } 

    var emp = 0;

    do
    {
        for (var row = 1; row <= numberOfRows; row++) {
            var tableRowDiv = document.createElement('div');
            dataContainer.appendChild(tableRowDiv);

            var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
            tableRowDiv.appendChild(tableRow);

            for (var col = 1; col < 4; col++)
            {
                if (emp < employeeData.length) {
                    var tableCol = document.createElement('td');
                    tableCol.className = 'pdf-employee-box';
                    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

                    var empName = document.createElement('div');
                    empName.className = 'fw-bold';
                    empName.innerHTML = `${employeeData[emp].firstName} ${employeeData[emp].lastName}`;
                    tableCol.appendChild(empName);

                    var empPhoto = document.createElement('img');

                    var employeePhotoUrl = employeeData[emp].azurePhotoURL;
                    if (employeePhotoUrl == null) {
                        empPhoto.src = '/Images/lg_unavailable.jpg';
                    } else {
                        empPhoto.src = employeePhotoUrl;
                    }

                    var empPhotoOnError = document.createAttribute('onerror');
                    empPhotoOnError.value = "this.onerror=null;this.src='/Images/lg_unavailable.jpg';";
                    empPhoto.setAttributeNode(empPhotoOnError);

                    empPhoto.alt = 'Employee Photo';
                    empPhoto.className = 'employee-photo-pdf pdf-image';
                    tableCol.appendChild(empPhoto);

                    var empTitle = document.createElement('div');
                    empTitle.innerHTML = employeeData[emp].title != null ? `Title: ${employeeData[emp].title}` : 'Title: Unknown';
                    empTitle.className = 'pdf-details';
                    tableCol.appendChild(empTitle);

                    var empDept = document.createElement('div');
                    empDept.innerHTML = employeeData[emp].department != null ? `Department: ${employeeData[emp].department}` : 'Department: Unknown';
                    empDept.className = 'pdf-details';
                    tableCol.appendChild(empDept);

                    var empEmail = document.createElement('div');
                    empEmail.innerHTML = (employeeData[emp].emailAddress != null && !employeeData[emp].emailAddress.toLowerCase().includes('no ')) ? `Email: ${employeeData[emp].emailAddress}` : 'Email: Unknown/None';
                    empEmail.className = 'pdf-details';
                    tableCol.appendChild(empEmail);

                    var empStartDate = document.createElement('div');
                    empStartDate.innerHTML = employeeData[emp].startDate != null ? `Start Date: ${employeeData[emp].startDate}` : 'Start Date: Unknown';
                    empStartDate.className = 'pdf-details';
                    tableCol.appendChild(empStartDate);

                    var empLocation = document.createElement('div');
                    empLocation.innerHTML = employeeData[emp].location != null ? `Location: ${employeeData[emp].location}` : 'Location: Unknown';
                    empLocation.className = 'pdf-details';
                    tableCol.appendChild(empLocation);

                    if (col == 2) tableCol.className = tableCol.className + ' pdf-grid-lines';

                    emp++;
                }  
            }

            if (emp % 9 == 0) {
                tableRowDiv.className += 'page-break-after';
            }
        }
    } while (emp < employeeData.length)
    
    
}
```

I decided to calculate the number of rows I need based on how many employee records we have.  So, if we have 436 employees, then I'm determining that I need 146 rows.  So I'm programming it to generate the precise number of rows I need, and only put 3 items (columns) in each row.  The 146th row in this case only has 1 record.

As you can see, I have the code in a loop only running until it reaches the last employee, so that it doesn't throw an index out of range exception.

This particular code is where I am telling the table to break to the next page, so that employee records aren't running over onto another page and splitting up the information.

```
if (emp % 9 == 0) {
   tableRowDiv.className += 'page-break-after';
}
```

Here is the CSS that I'm referencing in an external CSS file:

```
@media print {
    .page-break-after {
        break-after: page;
    }
}
```

I understand that I am by no means the ultimate programming kingpin, so there could be better or easier ways of doing this.  However, this is how I made it work with my environment and it does exactly what I need it to do without using some framework or library.

I found in my research that many PDF generator frameworks, libraries, etc. now require licensing.  So if generating a printable document is your goal, then this could work for you too.  Anyways, good luck and I hope I have helped someone.